# How to create a web service with method taking two parameters

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

For example, I have to create a webservice with a details below:

Webservice name is WS1
Method name is initiateBatchProcess (String Status, int BatchID)

I have tried the following with one parameter, but how do I do it with two parameters and return it in the response of webservice/soap

```
public class WS1 
{
    int status;

    @WebMethod(operationName="status")
    public int status(int status) {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is an example .. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/WebMethodWithReturnTypeAndParameters.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply add another parameter. The use of the @WebParam is optional, keep it if you want or ditch it.

```
@WebMethod(operationName="initBatch")
public void initiateBatchProcess(@WebParam(name = "Status") String Status, 
                   @WebParam(name = "Batch") int BatchID) {
      //do stuff
}
```

LE:

So, if you want to send back more than one thing, the best solution i can think of is encapsulating those things into a single object.

```
@WebMethod(operationName="initBatch")
public RezultSet initiateBatchProcess(String status, int batchID) {

      //do stuff

    ResultSet result = new ResultSet();
    result.setStatus(status);
    result.setBatchId(batchID);
    return result;
    /*
    *Or you can do something like 
    *return new ResultSet(status, batchID);
    */

}
```

And ResultSet is just a simple bean with 2 members.

```
public class ResultSet {

    private String status;
    private int batchID;

    // getters, setters, constructors

}
```

Comment: But how do I return them in response is my problem

Comment: If I pass only one parameter then I can say "return status" but when I pass two parameters then how do I return them ?

Comment: So, if i understand corectly, you want to return more than one parameter? I will return with an edit for that case

Comment: I hope I understand what you want and that my answer helped.